# MediaPlayer Android Studio Error when removed Artist Name

Tags: android

I was making a Music App.
The app ran fine, but when I removed ARTIST NAME the app crashes !!

**THIS CODE RUNS FINE:**

```
private void getMusic() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri songUri       = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int songTitle  = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do {
                String currentTitle  = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);

                arrayList.add("Title:  " + currentTitle + "\n" + "Artist: " + currentArtist);
            } while (songCursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
```

---

**THIS GIVES ME ERROR:**

```
private void getMusic() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri songUri       = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int songTitle  = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do {
                String currentTitle  = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);

                arrayList.add("Title:  " + currentTitle);
            } while (songCursor.moveToNext());

        }

    }
```

*I just have removed current Artist Name from the code.*

**HERE'S THE ERROR:**

> > E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >         Process: com.innocentapps.innocentmusic, PID: 4255
> >         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.innocentapps.innocentmusic/com.innocentapps.innocentmusic.MainActivity}:
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> >     'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
> >     reference
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
> >          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> >     java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on
> >     a null object reference
> >             at com.innocentapps.innocentmusic.MainActivity.getMusic(MainActivity.java:69)
> >             at com.innocentapps.innocentmusic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
> >             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
> >             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
> >             at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977) 
> >             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> >             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
> >             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923) 
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
> >             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870) 
> >     W/System: A resource failed to call close.  Application terminated.

**Adapter**

private void fetchingSongsToList() {

```
    listOfSongs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfSongs);
    arrayList   = new ArrayList<>();
    getMusic();

    adapter     = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listOfSongs.setAdapter(adapter);

    listOfSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Play the selected Music

        }
    });
```

Comment: `arrayList` appears to be `null`, based on your stack trace.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that removing the name is the only change you made? Because it seems like the error is not in the code you posted but somewhere else.

Comment: @CommonsWare what should I do? :-(

Comment: @pappbence96 yes... Nothing else was changed .. only divider height was changed in XML to 10sp

Comment: You will need to determine why `arrayList` is `null`. We cannot help you with that, as we do not know where you are initializing `arrayList`, and we do not see where you are calling `getMusic()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare getMusic() is to get music from device and get it's artist name and stuff

Comment: @CommonsWare updated the code .. please check the adapter now